# Taskbar on Secondary Monitor disappears when an application is Maximized

Tags: taskbar, windows-11

I upgraded my Windows 10 PC to Windows 11 today.  I have a two monitor setup and I noticed that on my **secondary monitor only**, when I maximize any application the task bar disappears, despite having the task bar setting "Automatically hide the taskbar" unchecked.  The .gif illustrates what I mean:

[image: taskbar gif]

It's almost as if I pressed <kbd>F11</kbd> in Chrome to go full screen, but that isn't the case.  Weirdly however, if I do press <kbd>F11</kbd> in Chrome to go full screen and then press <kbd>F11</kbd> again to exit it, the taskbar shows back up. If I maximize again though, the taskbar again disappears.

My taskbar settings are so:

[image: taskbar settings]

This is on Windows 11 Version 21H2 (build 22000.556).

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to have resolved itself after a restart/power off (I actually shut my PC down completely as I normally do for the night).  Obviously I should have probably tried that first, but I was under the impression that the restarts performed when installing Windows 11 ruled this out already.  I haven't had the issue occur anymore since powering off my PC and powering it on again.

There was some updates that were also downloaded and installed that maybe addressed the issue, but I think they were mainly around the .NET Framework and not any kind of Windows Features updates.

Answer (score 1):

you can also kill "explorer.exe" with taskmanager and start it again, worked for me
also you could run in cmd "taskkill /f /im explorer.exe" followed by "explorer.exe"

Comment: This works great.  For what it's worth it happened to me on my Primary monitor only.  It's also a monitor I use Dell Display Manager to switch between Display Port and HDMI inputs, so I suspect it's related to switching displays and/or sleep mode, but I haven't been able to reproduce..